# Where can I download gaviota endgame tables?

Tags: endgame, tablebases

I am looking for a link to download all 5 pieces gaviota endgame tables (which can give me DTM values).

A few links from google search ([like this](https://sites.google.com/site/gaviotachessengine/Home/endgame-tablebases-1)) lead me to the [site which does not exist](http://www.olympuschess.com/egtb/gaviota/).

Comment: It looks like you could install Gaviota itself, and then use the included [tbgen](https://sites.google.com/site/gaviotachessengine/Home/endgame-tablebases-1/gtb-generation) utility to generate the tablebases directly on your own machine, barring other options.

Comment: @ETD, thanks I know that I can generate them myself, but I thought that these tables are used frequently enough and can be found easily on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://chess.cygnitec.com/tablebases/gaviota/

Use wget recursively: https://serverfault.com/questions/25199/using-wget-to-recursively-download-whole-ftp-directories for all the files.

Answer (score 0):

lucas chess has them any many more, download lucaschess for free